# Changing more than one element's data-src to src upon .load() in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, image, function, attributes, src

I am trying to figure out a way to change more than one element's attribute from `data-src` to `src` upon loading content from an external PHP file. So far, I have only partially succeeded with the code below, as it does perform the function, but only on the **first** `img` element loaded, while the other `img` element loaded remains unaffected. How can I select **both** `img` elements and apply the `data-src` to `src` action upon `.load()`?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".imginset").load('PATHTOURL.php img:lt(1)' , function() {
        $("img").each(function() {
            $(this).attr("src",$(this).attr("data-src")).removeAttr("data-src");
        }); 
    });
});
```

The HTML:

From the external PHP file:

```
<a href="LINK1">
    <img data-src="IMGURL1.jpg" alt="">
</a>
<a href="LINK2">
    <img data-src="IMGURL2.jpg" alt="">
</a>
<a href="LINK3">
    <img data-src="IMGURL3.jpg" alt="">
</a>
```

and the HTML that is used to display the content:

```
<div class="imginset"></div>
```

Comment: Can you show your html? 
Is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291481/jquery-image-src-change-after-load

Comment: @jqueryHtmlCSS, I have added some HTML for reference. I have also adjusted a few things in the initial script, as well.

Comment: `img:lt(1)` is loading only the first img ?

Comment: @Richard No, it loads both img, but the attribute replacement function from data-src to src is only applying to the first image loaded

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, I was able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".imginset").load('PATHTOURL.php a>img:lt(2)',function(){
        $("img").each(function(){
            $(this).attr("src",$(this).attr("data-src")).removeAttr("data-src");
        }); 
    });
});
```

It appears that by specifying the parent element for each image, which in this case was `<a>`, it allowed for more than one `img` to be selected.